# Solving a Recurrence Relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

In my research, I encountered the following recurrence relation:

\begin{align}
g(t) &= (\beta-1) \; g(t-1) + \beta \; f(t)\\
f(t) &=\min\{f(t-1)+g(t-1),  \, c \cdot \lambda^t \}
\end{align}

where $1<\beta<2$ is a constant parameter,  $\lambda=\sqrt{1-(2/\beta -1)^2}$, and $c >1$ is another constant parameter. Also, $f(0) = g(0) = 1$.

I am familiar with linear recurrences, but not with sets of recurrences like this, so any help to direct me toward the answer is appreciated. If necessary, solving a relaxed version of the recurrence set where $f(t) =f(t-1)+g(t-1)$ would  be helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can at least get you to generating functions for the two sequences, in the relaxed case:

Let $F(z)$ and $G(z)$ be the generating functions for $f$ and $g$, respectively:
$$
F(z):=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}f(t)z^t\qquad G(z):=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}g(t)z^t
$$
Then
$$\begin{align*}
F(z)&=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}f(t)z^t\\
&=1+\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}f(t-1)z^{t}+\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}g(t-1)z^t\\
&=1+z\cdot F(z)+z\cdot G(z).\tag{1}
\end{align*}$$
and
$$\begin{align*}
G(z)&=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}g(t)z^t\\
&=1+(\beta-1)\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}g(t-1)z^t+\beta\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}f(t)z^t\\
&=1+(\beta-1)z\cdot G(z)+\beta(F(z)-1).\tag{2}
\end{align*}$$
From $(1)$, we see that 
$$
F(z)=\frac{1+zG(z)}{1-z}.
$$
Plugging this in to $(2)$ and solving yields
$$
G(z)=\frac{1+(\beta-1)z}{(\beta-1)z^2-2\beta z+1},
$$
from which we can also deduce that
$$
F(z)=\frac{1-2(\beta-1)z}{(\beta-1)z^2-2\beta z+1}.
$$
From here, your best bet is to factor the denominators and do a partial fraction decomposition; this will let you rewrite in terms of geometric series for explicit solutions (much like when using generating functions to find an explicit description of the Fibonacci sequence).